# Question with stack smashing protection and buffer overflows

Tags: c, security, gcc, buffer-overflow

Im doing some research on buffer overflows and I was wondering how does stack smashing protection works

i have this code:

```
int main( )
{ 
    char Buf[16];
    printf(“Digite o seu nome: ”);
    gets(Buf);
    printf(“%s”,Buf);
return 0;
}
```

I compile it with gcc

and then i put in a bunch of chars to fill the buffer

First i put 16 chars

> $ ./Exemplo1
>
> Digite o seu nome: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>
> Ola AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

This is ok because the buffer is the right size

Next i try 24 chars

> $ ./Exemplo1
>
> Digite o seu nome: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>
> Ola AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Why does it still works?

shouldn't this cause the program to terminate!?

It only terminates the program when I put 25 or more chars

> ./Exemplo1
>
> Digite o seu nome: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>
> Ola AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

*** stack smashing detected ***: ./Exemplo1 terminated

Why? what's after the buffer that is not the return address? 
What I read about and what I think understand is that it should have a canary value, but its supposed to terminate the program if that value has changed and with 24 chars written to the buffer shouldn't it still give me a stack smashing detected even if the return address hasn't changed but the canary value did.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this all of your code? Where is "Ola " coming from?

Comment: sry about that i edit the code and didn't realise =/
but i just changed the printf("%s\n", Buf); to 
printf("\n\nOla %s\n", Buf);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my brief reading of the generated assembly, here is what I think happens (gcc 4.4.5 on 64-bit Ubuntu).

The canary is a double word (8 bytes). The stack -- including the canary -- grows in increments of 16 bytes. The canary is placed right at the end of the stack frame. To satisfy all three requirements at the same time, `gcc` may need to insert padding between your automatic variables and the canary.

Since in your code `Buf` is 16 bytes long, `gcc` places 8 bytes of padding between `Buf` and the canary (needed in order to make the size of the stack frame a multiple of 16 bytes). This explains why you can enter up to 24 chars without triggering the stack smashing detection.

If I change `Buf` to be 8 bytes long, there's no longer need for any padding, and entering 9 chars triggers the protection:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( )
{ 
    char Buf[8];
    printf("Digite o seu nome: ");
    gets(Buf);
    printf("%s",Buf);
    return 0;
 }

aix@aix:~$ ./a.out 
Digite o seu nome: AAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAA

aix@aix:~$ ./a.out 
Digite o seu nome: AAAAAAAAA
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
```

Obviously, this is dependent on the compiler, hardware platform, compiler flags etc.

It also goes without saying that one shouldn't expect this mechanism to be bullet-proof.

If you'd like to experiment further, try compiling your code with different buffer sizes and with/without `-fno-stack-protector`. If you use `-S` to generate assembly code, you'll be able to see how the generated code changes as you tweak the settings.

Comment: Yes changing the buffer size to 8 works
I didn't know the stack would grow in increments of 16 bytes for everything I thought it was just for the buffer and the rest would be allocated as needed... Is it always 16 bytes for x64 processors?
Thanks a lot btw =D

Comment: Also this mean that the return address would start after the 32 byte after the start of the buffer?

Comment: @Renato: With regards to your first question, there is some flexibility afforded by the `-mpreferred-stack-boundary` gcc option. As to the second question, I encourage you to generate and read the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler makes no guarantees about how data will be organized on the stack. The buffer `buf[]` **could** be allocated right next to critical data like the canary, old stack pointer, and return address; or there could be some extra space in between. In this case, it looks as though there's probably some padding in there.

Answer (score 0):

The actual size of the buffer may be larger than the size you specify, or there is more on the stack beside the buffer. By going past the buffer boundary, you either write to the extra memory in the buffer, or you overwrite other content of the stack. That is not good, since it might trash some of your local variables, but it won't overwrite the return address yet.

Only if you write past the allocated local stack frame and overwrite the return address of the function that is currently executing, bad things can happen. If you are lucky, your program just crashes. But what will exactly happen is hard to foresee.

Answer (score 0):

Currently most compilers include stack cookies or another form of stack protection. Probably this is ProPolice at work http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#GCC_Stack-Smashing_Protector_.28ProPolice.29